# Is Realm DB file safe to be used as the permanent source of backup and restore?

Tags: realm

I've been wanting to allow users to backup their data as a full Realm DB file and also allow them to restore data using the same file anytime.

Will an old, Realm DB file be "always" fully compatible with the newest version of Realm?

The question might seem trivial, but it comes from my understanding that Realm is rapidly growing. So my concern only lies around the possibilities with that premise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, older versions of Realm can always be read by newer versions. However, changes to file format in some versions will mean that opening the file with a newer version will change the file so it is no longer compatible with older versions.